# Upload File to Database in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, image-uploading

I simply would like to upload a file to my database using ColdFusion.  I understand how to upload an image to a directory, but I would like to place it directly in the database.

I have set a database field to varbinary(MAX) to accept the image and have the stored procedure to insert it.  Currently my code for uploading the image to my file system is:

```
<cfif isdefined("form.FileUploadImage")> 
            <cffile action="upload" filefield="FileUploadImage" destination="#uploadfolder#" nameconflict="overwrite" accept="image/*" > 
</cfif>
```

I've obviously left some of the supporting code out, but really all I need to do is get a binary representation of the file stored in memory, instead of the file system.

Any experts out there that can help?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<cfquery>
  INSERT INTO Image (Jpg) 
  VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam CFSQLType="CF_SQL_BLOB"
                  value="#ToBase64(FileReadBinary(uploadedFilePath))#">
</cfquery>
```

Later if you want to stream the image back to the browser, use `<cfimage>` (CF8+)

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass saving the image to the file system?  That's really my true goal.

Comment: not really, unless you use Virtual File System (RAM Disk) in CF9.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Appreciate it though!

Answer (score 5):

The way to bypass saving file to the file system:

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob"
              value="#FileReadBinary(FORM.FileUploadImage)#">
```

Comment: This worked for me in ACF10; I observed that the value of the FORM field is an internal CF path, such as: C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\work\Catalina\localhost\tmp\neotmp8293497696930332477.tmp